# Docker doesn't bind ports

Tags: docker

Why doesn't exposed ports from a docker container work?

Let's consider the following example

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install netcat strace

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["strace", "nc", "-l", "8080"]
```

cmd to run `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --cap-add SYS_PTRACE ex_001`

And any attempt to send something via `echo "TRALALA" | nc -v localhost 8080` results into `Connection to localhost 8080 port [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!` but that's all.

The strace instance in the container prints nothing. Why?

I.e. strace hangs on waiting of a new accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `-p` option to specify the local port for listening. Otherwise it interprets the number as a hostname.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["strace", "nc", "-vlp", "8080"]
```

Switching on verbose mode makes it more clear what `nc` is doing.

Comment: it's strange. On Ubuntu `nc -l 8080` works correctly. But on debian it causes a error without `-p`